# Php.ini changes are not taken on Linux Bitnami Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, bitnami

I am using a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) stack from Bitnami with Ubuntu. I am trying to increase *post_max_size* in file *php.ini*.

I changed these values:

```
post_max_size = 60M
upload_max_filesize = 60M
```

Then reset with `sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm` (taken from the Bitnami documentation). No changes take effect.

I have tried removing all the text from *php.ini*. I get date errors at the top of [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), but it still shows the *post_max_size* is 20M. I tried to `sudo vi /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini`. It is showing all my changes. I run phpinfo(). It says:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path    /bitnami/lampstack-linux-x64/output/php/lib
Loaded Configuration File    /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini
```

It still has the wrong 20 MB as *post_max_size*. This is nowhere in that INI file. I have looked at all other .ini files on my server, but it is not in any of them.  I have stopped and started both *php-fpm* and Apache to make sure they took down my site, and they both did.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There maybe more than one `php.ini` check with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` where you php gets its ini file from

Comment: It says Loaded Configuration File  /opt/bitnami/php/etc/php.ini . This is what Im changing.

Comment: What are your rules about overriding in your VHost/Server configuration? In general, if you have write access to the server configuration, then avoid .htaccess, because it will usually slow down your webserver.

Comment: @norebu I got rid of the stuff from htaccess, I was just saying that I couldnt get that to work either.  I want to use the php.ini

Comment: Did you try to turn off Apache, modify your `php.ini` and restart Apache?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  I have no clue why this isnt working :/

Comment: Do you have a `fpm/php.ini`? somewhere

Comment: No fpm/php.ini.  I checked all the php.ini files on my server.  None of them have 20M set as the post_max_size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the file:

```
/opt/bitnami/apps/prestashop/conf/php-fpm/php-settings.conf
```

And do:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm
```